# How to resolve, list index out of range, from scraping website?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
with open("COVID-19 pandemic in the United States - Wikipedia.htm", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fd:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(fd)

print(soup.prettify())

all_tables = soup.find_all("table")
print("The total number of tables are {} ".format(len(all_tables)))

data_table = soup.find("div", {"class": 'mw-stack stack-container stack-clear-right mobile-float-reset'})
print(type(data_table))

sources = data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[0]

sources_list = [td for td in sources.findAll('td')]

print(len(sources_list))


data = data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1].findAll('td', recursive=False)

data_tables = []

for td in data:

    data_tables.append(td.findAll('table'))

header1 = [th.getText().strip() for th in data_tables[0][0].findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')]

header1
```

For some reason, the last line with header one gives me an error, "list index out of range". I am not too sure what is causing this error to happen, but I know I need this line. Here is a link to the website I am using for the data, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States. The specific table I want is the one that is below the horizontal bar chart.

---

## Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-67ef2aac7bf3> in <module>
     28     data_tables.append(td.findAll('table'))
     29 
---> 30 header1 = [th.getText().strip() for th in data_tables[0][0].findAll('thead')[0].findAll('th')]
     31 
     32 header1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

[image]

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html)

- *Read HTML tables into a `list` of `DataFrame` objects.*
- This answer side-steps the question to provide a more efficient method for extracting tables from Wikipedia and **gives the OP the desired end result**.
- The following code will more easily get the desired table from the Wikipedia page.
- `.read_html` will return a list of dataframes.

  - The table you're interested in, is at index `4`
- Clean the table

  - Select the rows and columns with valid data.
  - This method does return the table headers, but the column names are multi-level so we'll rename them.

    - [image]
    - **Before renaming the columns**, if you need the original data from the column names, use `us_covid_data.columns` which will return a list of tuples with all the column name values.

```py
import pandas as pd

# get list of dataframes and select index 4
us_covid_data = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States')[4]

# select rows and columns
us_covid_data = us_covid_data.iloc[0:56, 1:6]

# rename columns
us_covid_data.columns = ['state_territory', 'cases', 'deaths', 'recovered', 'hospitalized']

# display(us_covid_data)
             state_territory   cases deaths recovered hospitalized
0                    Alabama   45785   1033     22082         2961
1                     Alaska    1184     17       560           78
2             American Samoa       0      0         –            –
3                    Arizona  116892   2082         –         5272
4                   Arkansas   24253    292     17834         1604
5                 California  296499   6711         –            –
6                   Colorado   34316   1704         –         5527
7                Connecticut   46976   4338         –            –
8                   Delaware   12293    512      6778            –
9       District of Columbia   10569    561      1465            –
10                   Florida  244151   4102         –        15150
11                   Georgia  111211   2965         –        11919
12                      Guam    1272      6       179            –
13                    Hawaii    1012     19       746          116
14                     Idaho    8222     94      2886          350
15                  Illinois  151767   7144         –            –
16                   Indiana   49560   2698     36788         7139
17                      Iowa   31906    725     24242            –
18                    Kansas   17618    282         –         1269
19                  Kentucky   17526    623      4785         2662
20                 Louisiana   66435   3296     43026            –
21                     Maine    3440    110      2787          354
22                  Maryland   70497   3246         –        10939
23             Massachusetts  111110   8296     88725        10985
24                  Michigan   73403   6225     52841            –
25                 Minnesota   38606   1511     33907         4112
26               Mississippi   31257   1114     22167         2881
27                  Missouri   24985   1077         –            –
28                   Montana    1249     23       678           89
29                  Nebraska   20053    286     14641         1224
30                    Nevada   22930    537         –            –
31             New Hampshire    5914    382      4684          558
32                New Jersey  174628  15479     31014            –
33                New Mexico   14549    539      6181         2161
34                  New York  400299  32307     71371            –
35            North Carolina   81331   1479     55318            –
36              North Dakota    3858     89      3350          218
37  Northern Mariana Islands      31      2        19            –
38                      Ohio   57956   2927         –         7292
39                  Oklahoma   16362    399     12432         1676
40                    Oregon   10402    218      2846         1069
41              Pennsylvania   93876   6880         –            –
42               Puerto Rico    8714    157         –            –
43              Rhode Island   16991    960         –         1922
44            South Carolina   47214    838         –            –
45              South Dakota    7105     97      6062          689
46                 Tennessee   51509    646     31020         2860
47                     Texas  240111   3013    122996         9610
48            Virgin Islands     112      6        79            –
49                      Utah   25563    190     14448         1565
50                   Vermont    1251     56      1022            –
51                  Virginia   66740   1881         –         9549
52                Washington   38517   1370         –         4463
53             West Virginia    3461     95      2518            –
54                 Wisconsin   35318    805     25542         3574
55                   Wyoming    1675     20      1172          253
```

### Addressing the original issue:

- `data` is an empty list generated from `data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1].findAll('td', recursive=False)`

  - With `data = data_table.tbody.findAll('tr', recursive=False)[1]` and then `data = [v for v in data.get_text().split('\n') if v]`, you will get the headers.

    - The output of `data` will be `['U.S. state or territory[i]', 'Cases[ii]', 'Deaths', 'Recov.[iii]', 'Hosp.[iv]', 'Ref.']`
- Since `data_tables` is generated from iterating through `data`, it is also empty.
- `header1` is generated from iterating `data_tables[0]`, so `IndexError` occurs because `data_tables` is empty.

Comment: Thank you! And would it be possible to convert this into a dataframe so I can do manipulations?